# What to include in NetBeans to use JSTL tags?

Tags: jsp, netbeans, jstl

I got this error while using JSTL tags in JSP

The code is:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

The output is:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTag
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:342)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Comment: Click on the "jstl" tag at the bottom of your question, then click the "info" tab, and read.

Answer (score 2):

1 . Expand your **Netbeans project**
2 . Right click on libraries folder inside ur project

[image]

3 . Click on **Add Library** in pop-up menu

4 . Click in the window and Type Jstl

[image: jstl add library]

5 . click on Add library  ur done..!

  It will add Jstl.jar and standard.jar as shown below...

[image: done]

if you update Netbeanse further (if u could) then 
it woluld be **Jstl-1.2.jar**, but jstl.1.1 and standard is enough....! to program with JSTL.

Comment: always welcome and its pleasure.. to study more aboute jstl follow    **BalusC** comments and solutions in Stackoverflow  that man is the best i have seen ever for this job.